# Export Jupyter Notebook to PDF With Same Markdown Rendering

Tags: pdf, jupyter-notebook, latex, markdown, jupyter-lab

**Problem**
My notebook is solely Markdown and I would like to export it to a PDF with the same Markdown rendering that JupyterLab displays. However, the regular PDF export converts it to LaTex and then to a PDF and it looks nothing like how I want it formatted. I would rather not have to manually edit a Tex file every time I want to export a notebook to a PDF, especially since it is very time-consuming for large files.

Exporting to WebPDF looks much closer to the result I desire, however, the page size is all over the place and I would like it to be Letter size (8.5 x 11 inches).

**Question**
How can I control the page size on the WebPDF export?

**Bonus Question**
Is it possible to get the PDF to look the way it does on JupyterLab Markdown rendering, including the dark theme? (printing the page to PDF does a terrible job and makes all the text an image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I am a little confused by the question, but I will do my best to answer this.

First, I would like to introduce you to [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/). Pandoc is a document conversion system. This will let you control how your markdown is converted into a pdf or any other desired format that pandoc converts to. For additional formatting control, pandoc has support for templates. Which will allow you to customize exactly how that document is treated on export.

Now to address your page size question. I do not think that you can control this from markdown alone, however you can if you use pandoc. This can be done by adding some LaTeX code into your markdown file. You can find the information on how to control page size using LaTeX [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Page_size_and_margins). Once you add this LaTeX code, you can convert to pdf using pandoc and a [pandoc template](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates). Pandoc provides a number of default templates which will work fine. Here is an example of the command used to do this conversion:

pandoc /filepath/doc_name.md -o doc_name.pdf --template /file_path/pandoc-templates/default.latex

Bonus question:
You can make a custom pandoc template to replicate any formatting and rendering that is done in JupyterLab Markdown. I am not too familiar with JuypterLabs, but making pandoc templates is not too bad and pandoc provides great documentation available [here](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates).